# VB.Net Anding a byte and a double

Tags: vb.net, primitive-types, boolean-expression

during some code conversion from another persons VB.net project to C#, i have come across the following code:

```
Public Sub New(ByVal lbytModuleAddress As Byte, ByVal lbytRelayStateMask As Byte)
    Dim lintCounter As Integer

    mbytModuleAddress = lbytModuleAddress
    For lintCounter = 0 To 7
        If lbytRelayStateMask And (2 ^ lintCounter) Then
            mblnRelayState(lintCounter) = True
        Else
            mblnRelayState(lintCounter) = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Now m trying to convert this to C#, but im a little confused as to exactly the meaning of this line:

```
If lbytRelayStateMask And (2 ^ lintCounter) Then
```

Could someone please enlighten me? It appears there something going on behind the scenes (that ill have to examine further) however before i do i would just like to clarify the result of this if statement.

Am i correct in saying if either one of the sub-expressions equals zero then its false, otherwise its true? Sorry, im not too up to speed on VB.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lbytRelayStateMask And (2 ^ lintCounter) results in BIT number lintCounter, which is on or off. a bit is a boolean value. AND is a bit operation, not the AND in an IF

th author might have written too:

mblnRelayState(lintCounter) = (lbytRelayStateMask And (2 ^ lintCounter))

Comment: Thanks Martin. Any suggestions how this could be re-written in C#?

Comment: use & (single!) where basic uses AND.  ^ will be Math.Pow(2,lintCounter). see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I believe you are correct in your analysis.